# JSON paths with script filter doesn't seem to work with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, json, jsonpath

I have a table like this :

```
Member|Votes
------------
 John | doc
```

Where doc = `[{"Member": "Bob", "ScoreGiven": 7}, {"Member": "Clay", "ScoreGiven": 4}]`

According to [JSONpath](https://www.jsonpath.com), the following path works : `"$[?(@.ScoreGiven>5)]"`

But when I try the following SQL query : `SELECT JSON_REMOVE(Votes, "$[?(@.ScoreGiven>5)]") FROM MyTable`

I get the error :

> #3143 - Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 2.

Comment: What's the result if you replace `"$[?(@.ScoreGiven>5)]"` with `'$[?(@.ScoreGiven>5)]'`?

Comment: It doesn't change anything, I got the same error.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support all the syntax of JSONPath. In particular, it does not support the current node metacharacter `@`. Nor does it support filters or predicates. You should review the limited path expression syntax it does support here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax